# Object with static and const member variables

Tags: c++, oop, embedded

In an embedded c project I have several motors of different type.
The implementation has static and const variables, and supports sub types.

It looks something like this (simplified):

```c
// motor.h

// to be global/static
typedef struct
{
    int distance;
} motor_instance;

// to be const
typedef const struct motor_hwToken_s
{
    motor_instance *self;
    void (*setSpeedFunction)(const struct motor_hwToken_s *token, int speed);
    int hwPin;
} motor_hwToken_t;

extern motor_hwToken_t motor_A;
void setSpeed(const struct motor_hwToken_s *token, int speed);


// motor.c
void setSpeed(const struct motor_hwToken_s *token, int speed)
{
    token -> setSpeedFunction(token, speed);
}

// specialization for DC-motors
void setSpeed_dcMotor(const struct motor_hwToken_s *token, int speed);

// global variable
motor_dc_instance motor_A_instance;

// const variable, known at compile time
motor_hwToken_t motor_A =
{
    .self = &motor_A_instance,
    .setSpeedFunction = setSpeed_dcMotor,
    .hwPin = 0x04       // define an IO-Pin of some sort
};


// main.c
void main(void)
{
    setSpeed(&motor_A, 20);
}
```

While the code works, it's quite hard to read.
I assume an object oriented language would make more sense?

So my question is:

1. How could I implement this in c++?
2. Will the cpp compiler be able to optimize the const variables (e.g. put them in flash)?

Comment: Regarding 2: Implementation dependent. Depending on how and where you initialize a constant, the compiler can put it just about anywhere and may be able to eliminate it entirely. On the other hand, you may have to use some implementation-specific nudging to place it exactly where you want.

Comment: "While the code works, it's quite hard to read."  That's because of sloppy style, sloppy formatting and use of global variables, not because of the language. "I assume an object oriented language would make more sense?"  Not really, if you don't have any program design discipline, the choice of language is irrelevant. Neither C nor C++ will design the program for you. "Will the cpp compiler be able to optimize the const variables" That's not optimization, that's the compiler functioning as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following class structure would be suggested. Instead of function pointer just re-implement the set speed function.

```
//! Motor interface class with abstract functions.
class Motor {
  public:
    virtual ~Motor() = default;
    void set_hwPin(int pin) { hwPin = pin; };
    virtual void set_speed(int speed) = 0;

  private:
    int hwPin;
};

class MotorDC : public Motor {
  public:
    ~MotorDC() override = default;
    void set_speed(int speed) override {
      // Actual implementation for DC motors.
    }
};

class MotorAC : public Motor {
  public:
    ~MotorAC() override = default;
    void set_speed(int speed) override {
      // Actual implementation for AC motors.
    }
};

int main() 
{
  MotorDC mDC;
  mDC.set_pin(1);

  MotorAC mAC;
  mAC.set_pin(2);

  // To demonstrate use a pointer to the abstract base class.
  Motor* m;
  m = &mAC;
  m->set_speed(10);

  m = &mDC;
  m->set_speed(20);
};
```

Comment: Definitely a lot cleaner, thou I was hoping to keep the const for better performance. ATM everything goes on the stack, or can the compiler optimise it? Might be overthinking it :)

Comment: @Oktah *can the compiler optimise it* is always an interesting question. Polymorhic behaviour (Dynamic dispatch) doesn't come free of charge so this may be slower, but the compiler can do anything it wants to try to speed things up so long as the program behaviour is not affected. Sometimes you can make a good guess at performance, but the only way you can be sure you can do is crank up the optimizer and benchmark. If it meets your performance requirements, groovy. All done. If not, you'll want to profile the code and see where you shave off some work or maybe give the compiler a few hints.